# Rewrite rules doesn't work apache 1.3

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache-1.3

I'm using a couple of rewrite directives that always works before on apache2 but now trying a new shared hosting and the rewrite rules do not seem to get applied.

I've reduced the .htaccess files to the following essential rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /demo/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

As you can see, i want to rewrite every request to my index.php file in the demo folder from root.

So everything like http://www.example.com/demo/albums/show/1 should be processed by http://www.example.com/demo/index.php for a standard MVC setup. (I'm using CodeIgniter btw)

The directives above results in a 500 error, so i thought maybe because of some possible syntax differences between 1.3 and 2.x.

After some trail and error editing, i've found the rewrite rule itself to be at fault but i really don't understand why.

- Any ideas to why my rewrite rule doesn't work? it did before on lots of different servers.
- Suggestions how to fix it?

Note: mod_rewrite does work, i've written a small test to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your position, I'd probably look in the Apache error log first, then would try to eliminate one moving part by doing

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/demo/index.php$ /demo/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/demo/(.*)$ /demo/index.php/$1 [L]
```

If that worked, I'd try reintroducing RewriteBase.

Comment: Thanks, good tip, i've removed the RewriteBase directive and this results in a 200 response for the root .../demo/ , but any other results in a plain old 404 from apache (not handled by my script as i can tell from my logs).

Comment: I added a RewriteRule above to avoid an accidental rewrite. There's a way to do that with a RewriteCond, but that'd require coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

… before the rewrite rules? If `FollowSymLinks` is disabled mod_rewrite won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you’re running into an infinite recursion since `index.php/…` is also matched by `^(.*)$`. So try to exclude your target:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```